# ES6 module loading, passing in a parameter in the exported method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**Please note, I'm very new to ES6 and module loading etc.**

I'm using this lib

https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-async-component

I've followed the example and got it working. But now I'm having trouble with this piece of example code.

```
export default asyncComponent({
  resolve: () => System.import('./Product')
});
```

It has the path hardcoded i.e. *'./Product'*

My question is how do I pass in the path as a parameter instead of the hardcoded *'./Product'*

Comment: This has very little to do with ES6 modules and more to do with React and the async component library. Without knowing the system I would guess that the intended use of this is to be hard-coded in that you would have individual files for each async component and then the use of them from the template would trigger the correct file by name. I don't think this was designed to be a dynamicly resolved.

Comment: I see , Thank you